# Ruby win32ole returns List, need to convert to Array

Tags: ruby, win32ole

I am using the otalclient.dll for HP Quality Center Automation to determine the list of Test Sets off of Root. The ole method returns a List (specifically IFactoryList) and I am wondering what I would need to do to, or read to learn how to, convert the list to an Array.

Code:

```
qc_connection = WIN32OLE.new('tdapiole80.TDConnection')
qc_connection.InitConnectionEx connection_url
qc_connection.login connection_name, connection_pwd
qc_connection.Connect qcDomain, qcProject
tree_manager = qc_connection.TestSetTreeManager
test_set_factory = qc_connection.TestSetFactory
test_set_list = test_set_factory.NewList("")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the List cannot be converted to an array directly. .each does work though and so, if I was so inclined, I might be able to do:

```
list_to_array = Array.new

<List>.each do |list_item|
  list_to_array << list_item
end
```

However, by looking at the List in Visual Studio I realized I was simply looking for a member of the list item and instead grabbed it.

```
list_to_array = Array.new

<List>.each do |list_item|
  list_to_array << list_item.Name
end
```

Comment: You could map rather than each.